# How to parse column of table that contain json array to table in asp.net core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a problem.
I have a column in my table that contains a JSON array, and I need to get this value and display it as a table in a cshtml view

I created a method that returns JSON of this value.

```
public ActionResult GetComposant(String fam)
    {
        var ComposantInfo = ((_context.Fds.Where(e => e.Fam == fam)).ToList()).Select(e => e.Chap2).FirstOrDefault();
        Debug.Write(ComposantInfo);



        return Json(ComposantInfo);
    }
```

In myjquery script I have:

```
  $.getJSON("GetComposant", { fam: selectedVal.toString() }, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.length);


            if (result.length == 0) {
                $('#msg').text("CeTTE FAMILLE n'a pas de FDS , veuillez la creer ");
                $('#msg').css('color', 'red')
                var tr;
                //Append each row to html table

                tr = $('<tr style="background-color: indianred;"/>');

                tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td contenteditable='true'>" + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);

            }
            else {
                $('#msg').text("FDS existe déja");
                $('#msg').css('color', 'green')
                var tr;
                //Append each row to html table
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + result[i].designe + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + result[i].ncas + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + result[i].symbole + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + result[i].poids + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + result[i].rphrases + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            }



        })
```

I tried to display the result in my console :
it displays:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYsOj.png)

that contains three elements, but when I tried to display the length it display 603

and showed me 603 line of undefined columns.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the json "string" into an actual js "object" to be able to access it via indexes:

```js
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(result);
// after that you are able to access it's properties
jsonObj [i].designe
```

Comment: your solution is perfect , thanks